# Get data from RDS PostgreSQL in Lambda function with nodejs

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

Problem I try get data from RDS PostgreSQL via Lambda function with Nodejs but response return is message

> Execution result: failed with "errorMessage": "2017-07-05T15:05:27.425Z 596fdf39-6193-11e7-9176-f58796899f9b Task timed out after 3.00 seconds" }

This snip code:

```
 const pg = require('pg');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var conn = "pg://string connect database";

    var client = new pg.Client(conn);

    client.connect();
    var resss = [];
    var idUser = 2;
    var query = client.query({
        text: 'SELECT * from users where id= $1',
        values: [idUser]
    });
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
       result.addRow(row);
    });

    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        resss.push(jsonObj);
        client.end();
        context.done(null, jsonObj);
       });
    callback(null, resss);
};
```

<

Comment: Does your Postgres instance allow traffic from your lambda? Is the connection timing out? If you have the lambda in a VPC do you have a NAT gateway setup?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was found a solved at here https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12. Same your answer.